# How to I change my nav bar from stacking up when window is smaller?

Tags: blogger

On my navigation bar, I want the icons to not stack below the nav bar when the window is smaller.

I bought the navigation bar from someone so I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.

stoleninspiration.com

Answer (score 0):

Use responsive css like conditional css with the help of media queries and make it.
I have idea but with get code I can not anything.
In which we can use conditional css and JQuery also.